# Drupal Page returning 502 error page instead of 404

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

When I am searching for a link from my drupal website https://example.com/index2.php?option=com_ckforms&view=ckforms&id=1&Itemid=190
i am getting 502(bad gateway) response and redirecting to 502 nginx error page instead of 404 as 5xx errors are reserved for actual service errors.

I am getting "upstream sent unsupported FastCGI protocol version: 72 while reading response header from upstream" error in logs.

I found that the reason could be- This server (Web Front-End) received an invalid response from an upstream (Web Back-End) server it accessed to fulfil the request.In most cases this will not mean that the upstream server is down, but rather that the upstream server and the gateway/proxy do not agree on the protocol for exchanging data.The problem is most commonly caused when there is a problem with IP communications between the Web Front and Back-Ends. Before you attempt to resolve this problem you should clear your browser cache completely.

Could anyone please suggest me

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

try_files $uri =404;

in nginx configuration file at location settings. This resolved my issue.